# Change the algorithm enumeration in the algorithm2e package

Tags: languages, naming, algorithm2e

I would like to translate the algorithm enumeration into another language, it is always printed in English:

- Algorithm 1 [Title]
- Algorithm 2 [Title]
- ...

I am using the algorithm2e package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `algorithmic` environment, you're probably using the [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) or possibly the [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) (both provide that environment). The `algorithm` environment's name is stored in `\ALG@name` that you can modify using `\renewcommand`.

Here's a way to modify the default `Algorithm` to your liking:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Algoritme}% Afrikaans
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Hierdie is 'n algoritme.}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Iets
    \State Iets anders
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}​
```

Note that this is actually independent of the `algorithmic` environment.

---

The [`algorithm2e` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) is a more complete package in the sense that it provides its own `algorithm` environment. It also supports a number of language options by default, including `english`, `french`, `czech`, `german`, `portuguese`, `italiano`, and `slovak`. For example, using (from the [`algorithm2e` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

These language options set a number of commands other than just the algorithm name (stored in `\algorithmcfname`). Here's an extract for the `portuguese` language option:

```
\DeclareOption{portuguese}{%
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmcfname}{Lista de Algoritmos}%
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Algoritmo}%
\renewcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{algoritmo}%
\renewcommand{\algorithmcflinename}{linha}%
\renewcommand{\algocf@typo}{}%
\renewcommand{\@algocf@procname}{Procedimento}%
\renewcommand{\@algocf@funcname}{Fun\c{c}\~{a}o}%
\renewcommand{\procedureautorefname}{procedimento}%
\renewcommand{\functionautorefname}{fun\c{c}\~{a}o}%
\renewcommand{\algocf@languagechoosen}{portuguese}%
}%
```

If your language is not supported here, you can perform the manual redefinitions yourself using a similar setup to the language settings above. If you just have a couple of changes that doesn't affect many components of your document, using

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Algoritme}% Afrikaans "Algorithm"
```

should work. You may also want to define your keywords accordingly.

Comment: I've been looking at the wrong package, I am using the algorithm2e package.

Comment: @platzhirsch: [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) is shipped with a number of language options. I've updated my answer to reflect those.